# How exactly Tensor masking and indexing should be done in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been using TF for 2 years now and at each project, I have lots of non-sense error popping out for masking which usually are not helpful and don't indicate what actually is wrong. or worst than that, the result is wrong but no error. I always test the code outside the training loop with dummy data and it's fine. but in the training (calling fit), I don't understand what TensorFlow expects exactly. just for one example, can someone experienced please tell me why this code does not work for a binary cross-entropy, the result is wrong and model does not converge but no error in this case:

```
class MaskedBXE(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        y_true = tf.squeeze(y_true)
        mask = tf.where(y_true!=2)
        y_true = tf.gather_nd(y_true, mask)
        y_pred = tf.gather_nd(y_pred, mask)
        loss = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
        return tf.reduce_mean(loss)
```

while this works correctly:

```
class MaskedBXE(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        mask = tf.where(y_true!=2, True, False)
        y_true = y_true[mask]
        y_pred = y_pred[mask]
        loss = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
        return tf.reduce_mean(loss)
```

and for a categorical example, the opposite is true. I can't use the mask as an index like y_pred[mask], or y_pred[mask[0]], or using tf.squeeze() and so on. but using tf.gather_nd() works. I always try all the combination that I think is possible, I just don't get it why something so simple should be this hard and painful. is Pytorch like this too? I'm happy to switch if you know Pytorch doesn't have similar annoying details.

**EDIT 1:** They work correctly outside training loop, or graph mode to be more exact.

```
y_pred = tf.random.uniform(shape=[10,], minval=0, maxval=1, dtype='float32')
y_true = tf.random.uniform(shape=[10,], minval=0, maxval=2, dtype='int32')

# first method
class MaskedBXE(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        
    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        y_true = tf.squeeze(y_true)
        mask = tf.where(y_true!=2)
        y_true = tf.gather_nd(y_true, mask)
        y_pred = tf.gather_nd(y_pred, mask)
        loss = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
        return tf.reduce_mean(loss)

    def get_config(self):
        base_config = super().get_config()
        return {**base_config}

# instantiate
mbxe = MaskedBXE()
print(f'first snippet: {mbxe(y_true, y_pred).numpy()}')


# second method
class MaskedBXE(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        mask = tf.where(y_true!=2, True, False)
        y_true = y_true[mask]
        y_pred = y_pred[mask]
        loss = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
        return tf.reduce_mean(loss)
    
    def get_config(self):
        base_config = super().get_config()
        return {**base_config}
    
# instantiate
mbxe = MaskedBXE()
print(f'second snippet: {mbxe(y_true, y_pred).numpy()}')
```

first snippet: 1.2907861471176147

second snippet: 1.2907861471176147

**EDIT 2:** After printing losses in graph mode as @jdehesa suggeted, they differ, which they shouldn't:

```
class MaskedBXE(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        # first
        y_t = tf.squeeze(y_true)
        mask = tf.where(y_t!=2)
        y_t = tf.gather_nd(y_t, mask)
        y_p = tf.gather_nd(y_pred, mask)
        loss = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_t, y_p)
        first_loss =  tf.reduce_mean(loss)
        tf.print('first:')
        tf.print(first_loss, summarize=-1)
        # second
        mask = tf.where(y_true!=2, True, False)
        y_t = y_true[mask]
        y_p = y_pred[mask]
        loss = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_t, y_p)
        second_loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
        tf.print('second:')
        tf.print(second_loss, summarize=-1)
        return second_loss
```

first:

0.814215422

second:

0.787778914

first:

0.779697835

second:

0.802924752

.
.
.

Comment: `mask = tf.where(y_true != 2, True, False)` is equivalent to just `mask = y_true != 2`. As far as I can tell the two snippets should be equivalent, can you give some example of `y_true` and `y_pred` where the result differ?

Comment: I'm happy to share code, but this snippet is from a very lengthy project I've done recently, and takes lots of reading. the summary of the problem in this case was that, I had a model for self-supervised learning, and there were multiple outputs after the shared body of network. while I was using the first approaach I realized my model does not converge and learns nothing. on the other hand, the second code block solved the problem! and for some categorical output, the opposite of these code blocks worked, using tf.gather worked but masking as index was not possible. I can share code if needed

Comment: No, I was thinking that maybe you could kind of have a "peek" inside the values, e.g. with `tf.print(y_true, summarize=-1); tf.print(y_pred, summarize=-1)` (and also `loss` in each case maybe). You could temporarily add both computations in the loss just to see what is the result you get from each one.

Comment: I added something to the question. the result is the same as expected outside the graph mode. I have to do what you suggested and see why this happens in the training loop.

Comment: @jdehesa Yes, they do differ in graph mode, when I call fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are inadvertently doing broadcasted operations in the first version, which is giving you the wrong result. This will happen if you batches have shape `(?, 1)`, because of the `tf.squeeze` operation. Note the shapes in this example

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Make random y_true and y_pred with shape (10, 1)
tf.random.set_seed(10)
y_true = tf.dtypes.cast(tf.random.uniform((10, 1), 0, 3, dtype=tf.int32), tf.float32)
y_pred = tf.random.uniform((10, 1), 0, 1, dtype=tf.float32)

# first
y_t = tf.squeeze(y_true)
mask = tf.where(y_t != 2)
y_t = tf.gather_nd(y_t, mask)
tf.print(tf.shape(y_t))
# [7]
y_p = tf.gather_nd(y_pred, mask)
tf.print(tf.shape(y_p))
# [7 1]
loss = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_t, y_p)
first_loss =  tf.reduce_mean(loss)
tf.print(tf.shape(loss), summarize=-1)
# [7]
tf.print(first_loss, summarize=-1)
# 0.884061277

# second
mask = tf.where(y_true!=2, True, False)
y_t = y_true[mask]
tf.print(tf.shape(y_t))
# [7]
y_p = y_pred[mask]
tf.print(tf.shape(y_p))
# [7]
loss = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_t, y_p)
tf.print(tf.shape(loss), summarize=-1)
# []
second_loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
tf.print(second_loss, summarize=-1)
# 1.15896356
```

In the first version, both `y_t` and `y_p` become broadcasted into 7x7 tensors so the cross-entropy is basically computed "all vs all", and then averaged. In the second case the cross-entropy is only calculated for each pair of corresponding values, which is the correct thing to do.

If you simply remove the `tf.squeeze` operation in the example above the result is corrected.

Comment: But why outside the tensorflow graph, the results are correct?! that's what I'm confused about.

Comment: @leo Ah I forgot about that part. The thing is when Keras gets training data in `fit` it assumes it has shape `(None, num_features)`, so your vectors with shape `(10,)` are automatically reshaped into `(10, 1)`, which is the shape that the loss function will actually receive on training. This can be convenient but also confusing, I have seen several similar problems in SO about that...